# How to convert an RDD of a multiple case classes into RDD of their components

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, case-class

I have a Spark RDD that is of a type of two case classes - something like this:

```
RDD[(ACTKey, UIDSKey)]
```

where case classes are defines the following way:

```
case class ACTKey(ACCOUNT: Int, PERIOD: String, COUNTRY: String)
case class UIDSKey(PRODUCT: String, UNIT: String, ID: Int)
```

When I'm saving it in a Hive table by calling dataframe.saveAsTable("MyTable", SaveMode.Overwrite) it creates a two-dimensional table structure:

```
_1 (struct<ACCOUNT:int,PERIOD:string,COUNTRY:string>)
_2 (struct<PRODUCT:string,UNIT:string, ID:int>)
```

I want to have a simple table structure like this:
ACCOUNT:int,PERIOD:string,COUNTRY:string, PRODUCT:string,UNIT:string, ID:int

One way to do that is to manually map my RDD into individual components of the case classe, like map(x=>(x._1.ACCOUNT, x._1.PERIOD,...etc)) but there is too much hard-coding that will have to change if my case classes change. So I'm looking for a more elegant solution like maybe to flatten the structure of my RDD that can be used for any RDD that is based on a set of case classes.

Comment: What about if you add another method like `extract` inside the `case class` something like `def extract = (this.ACCOUNT, this.PERIOD, this.COUNTRY)`

Comment: It is very similar to the mapping I described above and something I'm trying to avoid - hard-coding of the class attributes as in reality I have a large number of the attributes. Also they may change in the course of development and having them in multiple places may lead to missing some of them

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
rdd.toDF().select("_1.*", "_2.*")
  .write
  .format("parquet")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .saveAsTable("MyTable")
```

Comment: this didn't work with the following error:

    Caused by: parquet.schema.InvalidSchemaException: Cannot write a schema with an empty group: message root {
}